# unable to run 'yarn run build'

Tags: reactjs, build, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build my site.
It works when I run `yarn start`

Now I want to build it.

I run `yarn run build` and i get this error

```
yarn run build  
yarn run v1.22.17
warning package.json: No license field   
error Command "build" not found.
```

I have a package.json that contains the same script that allowed previous projects to run.

```
{
  "name": "bl_site_12_28",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.9.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.0.2",
    "chakra-ui-markdown-renderer": "^4.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.17.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-markdown": "^7.1.2",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.2"
  },    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried running `yarn run` as another post suggested to get a list of possible posts, but i get a similar message above. It seems that yarn is not reading my `package.json`

Comment: are you sure you're in the same directory? try using `ls` to see if package.json is in the same folder.

Comment: Thank you @KyleRifqi -- that was a bit of a miss sight on my end!

Comment: no problem. by the way, you can accept your own answer for anyone who sees this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

@KyleRifqi's helpful comment was all that was needed.
I used `ls` to identify the files in the current directly I was running `yarn run build` from.

I realized the `package.json` was not in that directory. I `cd` into the correct directory and then it worked